# Retrieving Specific Data from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Please help i want to retrieve a specific data from the Firebase Realtime database I have 2 users Professor and Student and i want to use that data for validations.

[FireBase Realtime Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC8Gv.png)

[image]

```
 firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                if(task.isSuccessful()){

                    //The task is successful || Task Login
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Successfully Login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        // If the users is professor but if it is student go to userStudent.class
                        finish();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),userProf.class));
```

[FireBase Realtime Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7PuO.png)

Comment: Please visit the official documentation to learn about FIrebase https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

Comment: I am building a role based app in firebase  i just need to fetch specific data for opening a new intent.

Comment: Have you checked the page? It has all you ever wanted

Comment: Yes i've already check it and its seems it is jsut for printing out the data my validations in the login activity if the user is professor it must go to prof Profile-r activity vice versa with the student

Comment: Hey , why did you unaccepted the Answer? Does it not solve your problem again? Instead of that, you can provide the problem you are facing and it will be improved. I invested my time on this, and it is improper if you keep doing this for the community.

Comment: Hi sorry for late replay, I am just new here in stack overflow community so i need first to adjust. Thank you for the support in this community but please take on easy on me.

Comment: Moving forward what should i put in here ("dbname") i try to change the code into ("Users") in my Firebase Realtime Database but when I'm doing login as student or professor it will go to professor profile activity

Comment: You didn't provide full database structure. but that should Your database name.

Comment: Also, the second answer looks promising. if you found this stressing you can try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for

```
FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser(); 
DatabaseReference reference;
firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){

                        //The task is successful || Task Login
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Successfully Login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                       reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().
                       getReference("dbname").child(user.getUid());


                       reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                       for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                       String usertype=datas.child("user").getValue().toString();

                       // If the users is professor but if it is 
                            // student go to userStudent.class
                       if(usertype.equals("Student")){

                         startActivity(new      
                         Intent(getApplicationContext(),studentProfile.class));
                         finish();

                       }else if (usertype.equals("Professor")) {
                         startActivity(new      
                         Intent(getApplicationContext(),professorProfile.class));
                         finish();
                       }

                      }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                  });






    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. I aiming for the fetching the specific data for a specific role so for example users is already registered as prof or student then as user logins to the app. If the users is professor then go to professor_profile_activity same as student if the users is a student then go to student_profile_activity. I'm am new here in stackoverflow please help then thanks a lot :)

Comment: You can use their userid

Comment: What do you mean in the different table? Then how to use their userid? :)

Comment: What you wanted to do is to check if current user is a professor or student, right? If so, code above is not for the solution. You will need a datasnapshot to check if user is either student or professor

Comment: Yes so how do i check it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            if(task.isSuccessful()){

                //The task is successful || Task Login
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Successfully Login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                 //user UID
                String userId = task.getResult().getUser().getUid();
                DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(userId);

                ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        String user = dataSnapshot.child("user").getValue(String.class);

                        if (user.equals("Student")) {

                         startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),userStudent.class));

                        } else if(user.equals("Professor")) {
                          startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),userProf.class));
                        }
                        finish();      

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
               });

}
```

Hope it helps